# can i convert an mp3 file with 64kbps bitrate to 192 kbps or 256 kbps etc?

Tags: audio

I have downloaded music from youtube and I am wandering wheather or how I can improve the quality of the sound. Is conversion to a higher bitrate possible? Is there anything else I could do? The music I have downloaded has a bitrate og 64kbps. Can I convert it to a higher bitrate and improve quality?

Comment: Doing as you suggest, you'd just end up with a bigger file that sounded the same (or worse, depending on the CODEC used).  You can't make up data to add quality.

Comment: This is the same as taking a low-res graphic and trying to blow it up in any universe other than CSI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can convert it. But you will end up with the file of bigger size and exactly the same, or sometimes slightly lower quality.